# Self adjoint and symmetric operator

Tags: operator-theory, adjoint-operators, differential-operators, positive-definite

I am wondering whether for an operator defined on a **real Hilbert space** to be positive we need to show that it is self-adjoint at first. It seems to me that they are two different property and can be studied independently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a complex Hilbert space, every positive operator is selfadjoint. But in a real Hilbert space, one can find positive operators which are not selfadjoint; for instance, 
$$
T=\begin{bmatrix}1&-1\\ 0&1\end{bmatrix}
$$
as an operator on $\mathbb R^2$ satisfies $\langle Tx,x\rangle\geq0$ for all $x$.

This ambiguity is common in the definition of real positive-definite matrices, where some people just require the positivity condition, while others also require the matrix to be symmetric (i.e., selfadjoint since all entries are real).

Answer (score 0):

Well, self adjoint implies $\langle Ax,x\rangle$ is real for all $x$ in the Hilbert space, and that better be the case if $\langle Ax,x\rangle \geq 0$ for all $x$.

In fact, positive operator implies self adjoint. Indeed, since $\langle Ax,x\rangle =\langle x,Ax\rangle=\langle A^*x,x\rangle$ for every $x$, we have $\langle (A^*-A)x,x \rangle =0$ for every $x$, which implies $A=A^*$.

Comment: Assuming, of course $A$ is bounded, so that we can even talk about its adjoint

Comment: So I guess as long as $<Ax,x> \in \mathbb{R}$ then the operator is self adjoint, right?

Comment: Right, $A$ is self adjoint if and only if $\langle Ax,x\rangle$ is real for every $x$, but only if you are in a complex (!) Hilbert space.

Comment: What if we deal with a real function space, your conclusion means that every operator defined on a real Hilbert space is self adjoint !?

Comment: It doesn't apply in the real case. Having the extra structure in the complex case gives that.

Comment: OK, I should have restricted my question to a real Hilbert space. If we deal with a real Hilbert space those concept (i.e. being self adjoint and positivity) are to be studied independently. Am I right?

Comment: They can be, yes.